# Why to post close vote so soon?

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-close

I recently have seen close-vote posting on question too soon. Even edits can work there. Why are some question even with enough upvotes facing close votes. We are in developing state all are new here, we should be more polite to each other rather then posting close vote why don't to communicate through comments if possible. Close vote should be last option rather then first, We can comment first or post an edit or help to reform question if possible. But close vote should be used as last option. What you guys think?

Answer (score 8):

Closing isn't forever; its purpose it to put a question on hold (note the "on hold" language) so that problems can be addressed before people start answering.  It's much harder to fix a question once it's attracted a variety of answers, each addressing a different possible interpretation of the question.

Use close *and* reopen votes to help us build good-quality answerable questions.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Monica. The vote close is actually a call to action for the site. A couple of things can happen there:

1. The question just closes and that's that.
2. Somebody figures out a way to reword the question (I did that recently with [How to determine if a cat is generally at an ideal weight?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/330/how-to-determine-if-a-cat-is-generally-at-an-ideal-weight)) that stops the close votes or convinced the community to reopen.

However, without the close activity, nothing may happen and the question languishes without proper responses or continuation.